# Loop through all items with desired file extension on QTreeView + QFileSystemModel

Tags: c++, qt

I'm completely newbie to Qt and C++, so I guess this is a very basic question, but I couldn't find it anywhere!

I'm using a QTreeView together with a QFileSystemModel to show the contents of a folder. When I need to loop though all selected items on it, I just use:

```
foreach (QModelIndex index, treeView->selectionModel()->selectedRows()) 
{
    //...
}
```

My question is:

Is there a similar way to loop through all items with desired file extension (for instance, *.aaa files)? If it can't be done exactly like this, please tell me how!

Edit: Just to make it clear, I'd want to loop through ALL files with given extension, not only the selected ones

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you just use a [`QDirIterator`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdiriterator.html)?

Comment: I can. As I said, I'm a newbie so I didn't know this option. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Using rowCount, columnCount and hasChildren, one should be able to run over all the elements of an QAbstractItemModel.
Does it help you?